# Partial views and html forms Asp Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am attempting to render a partial view that contains a simple html form. I want to render the form from a controller as I handle the postback from an overloaded controller method. I have tried @Html.Action("ContactForm")but I get an Exception because child actions cannot redirect.

My Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ContactForm()
{
    return PartialView(new ContactForm()); 
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ContactForm(ContactForm Contact)
{
    return RedirectToAction("FormResults", new { ContactForm = Contact });
}

public ActionResult FormResults(ContactForm Contact)
{
    return PartialView(Contact);
}
```

My Form:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    <h2>Contact Form</h2>
    <div class="input-group">
        <h4>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName, "First Name")</h4>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "First Name" })
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <h4>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.LastName, "Last Name")</h4>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Last Name" })
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <h4>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, "Email")</h4>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Email", @type = "text" })
    </div>

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit"  />
}
```

Any Help on how I would accomplish this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try surrounding the form with a div and a certain id and use:

```
@using(Ajax.BeginForm("ContactForm","YourController",new AjaxOptions()
{
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "yourCertainId",
    HTTPMethod = "POST"
})
```

and your ActionMethod:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ContactForm(ContactForm Contact)
{
    return Partial("YourPartialName", Contact });
}
```

make sure that you include the bundle jqueryval on the bottom of your view.

you wont need the second controller method "FormResults"

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this not work for you?

I don't think you need a redirect.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ContactForm(ContactForm Contact)
{
    return PartialView("FormResults", Contact);
}
```

This uses the

```
PartialView(string viewName, object model)
```

overload of the PartialView method in the Controller class.

This allows you to use a View that doesn't match the ActionResult's method name.

The same thing works for the plain "View" method as well.